# AppStore app downloaded to my xcode folder

Tags: macos, app-store

I bought my own application from the Mac AppStore. The app was not saved in the Applications folder, but instead in /Users/nathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2011-06-14/Release PackageTracking 6-14-11 12.09 PM.xcarchive/Products/Users/nathan

Is it just for me because I am the developer? Or are all my users going to have to hunt down that file? Why didn't it download it to the correct location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find and delete (or hide) absolutely every copy of your application (all debug copies, archive copies, anything with the same bundle ID) from your system before doing a test purchase.

You can try using Spotlight to find apps.

One way to hide apps is to compress them using gzip.  Or move them to a disk drive that can be unmounted.

Users with no previous copies of your app won't have this problem.  Users who have previous copies of your app and who put these copies in strange places might encounter this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess that it is because you already had a version of the app in that location from when you built it using the Archive option in Xcode.

The App Store would have detected that it has the same bundle ID and updated it in-place.